# Synergy will only work with Windows 7 machine as server?

Tags: windows-7, windows, synergy

I have installed Synergy version 1.3.6 on my Windows XP desktop and also on my Windows 7 laptop. When I run the laptop (Windows 7) as the server it works fine. But when I try to run the Desktop (running Windows XP) as the server it doesn't connect?

I'd really like to have the desktop as the server, the opposite is kind of pointless.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a firewall running on the Windows XP desktop which is preventing the laptop from connecting.

Comment: okay. so what can the OP do about that?

Comment: Turn off the firewall?  If that works, add a rule to allow Synergy traffic in from that host (TCP port 24800)